# System.Web.Security doesn't exist in assemblies

Tags: security, membership-provider, visual-studio-2013

Either i am late to the party or i did something wrong. I am working with Visual Studio 2013 and i was trying to use Membership class however, `using System.Web.Security;` namespace doesn't exist in my assemblies.

What can i do to solve this?

**Note: `System.Web` exists**

**Targeting: .NET Framework 4.5.1**

Comment: It looks like the System.Web.Security namespace is in System.Web.dll. Do you have that dll included?

Comment: @MillieSmith how to add dll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The System.Web namespace exists in System.dll

The System.Web.Security namespace exists in System.Web.dll

You can check this by going to the [System.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [System.Web.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespaces, opening one of the classes, and checking what the msdn article states is the dll (listed as the assembly).

Comment: I have read msdn and i am aware that it lives in `System.Web.Security`. Still no luck. Also note that i am Targeting: .NET Framework 4.5.1 not 4.5

Comment: If you target 4.5 does it work? That works for me... Are you sure you've added System.Web.dll as a reference to that project?

Comment: No, i don't see it in 4.5 either. Are you testing this in Visual Studio 2013? Is there another way i could install this library?

Comment: Namespace:  `System.Web.Security`
Assembly:  `System.Web` (in System.Web.dll)

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: Unfortunately I'm testing 2012. If this is really important, I can drive into work (about a 1 mile drive). My work has a 2013 install.

Comment: I know which namespace i need, its just that i can't add it because it is not in the Framework Assemblies.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: Maybe you're under Assembly -> Extensions instead of Assembly -> Framework? Obviously I'm shooting in the dark here. Just trying to help.

Comment: @MillieSmith No need to trouble yourself, i am sure someone on here will test it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @MillieSmith I considered that, still nothing. Anyways, i don't think it matters if you search for the specific assembly.

Comment: @MillieSmith worst moment ever, I wasn't reading your post carefully. All i needed to include was `System.Web` :(

Comment: @KomengeMwandila haha nice. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, in **.Net Framework 4+**, the namespace `System.Web.Security` lives in the `System.Web.ApplicationServices` assembly, look for that one in the references

Comment: +1, the class MembershipProvider exists in the System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly under the System.web.security namespace. as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had to reference System.Web AND System.Web.ApplicationServices to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Guess I'm way to late, but if anyone has not got an answer I finally found it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx

Add a Reference to:  WebMatrix.WebData (you need to choose "Extentions")
And you will have WebSecurity available

NOTE: You still need (System.Web.Security) for MemberShip & MemberShipUser

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Target framework from **.net client profile **  to  **.net**
2. Add `System.Web` assembly by references-->right click --> add references --> .net
3. On top add `using System.Web.Security;`